# Set property with wiremock random port in spring boot test

Tags: java, spring-boot, configuration, wiremock, spring-boot-test

I have a Spring Boot test that uses wiremock to mock an external service. In order to avoid conflicts with parallel builds I don't want to set a fixed port number for wiremock and would like to rely on its dynamic port configuration.

The application uses a property (`external.baseUrl`) set in the application.yml (under src/test/resources). However I didn't find a way to programmatically override that. I've tried something like this:

```
    WireMockServer wireMockServer = new WireMockServer();
    wireMockServer.start();
    WireMock mockClient = new WireMock("localhost", wireMockServer.port());
    System.setProperty("external.baseUrl", "http://localhost:" + wireMockServer.port());
```

but it didn't work and the value in application.yml was used instead. All other solutions that I've looked at override the property with a static value (for example in some annotation), but I don't know the value of the wiremock port until the test is run.

**Clarification:**

Both spring boot and wiremock run on random ports. *That's fine and I know how to get the value of both ports*. However wiremock is supposed to mock an external service and I need to tell my application how to reach it. I do this with the `external.baseUrl` property. The value I want to set in my test depends of course on the wiremock port number. **My problem is simply how to programmatically set a property in a spring boot test**.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Consider using [Spring Cloud Contract Wiremock](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/spring-cloud-contract.html#_spring_cloud_contract_wiremock)

There is already a JUnit Rule builder which allows to specify `${wiremock.port}` to set random port in property/yaml files

Or you can use `WireMockRestServiceServer` to bind WireMock to your `RestTemplate` so you don't even need to override URLs in your tests.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! I knew that there should be a standard solution for such a common problem!

Answer (score 13):

The property name mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/48859553/309683 (i.e. `wiremock.port`) is not correct, at least since Spring Cloud Contract version `2.1.2.RELEASE`.

#### 1. Working example

```java
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.cloud.contract.wiremock.AutoConfigureWireMock;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;
import static org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureWireMock(port = 0)
public class PortServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Test
    public void shouldPopulateEnvironmentWithWiremockPort() {
        assertThat(environment.containsProperty("wiremock.server.port")).isTrue();
        assertThat(environment.getProperty("wiremock.server.port")).matches("\\d+");
    }

}
```

#### 2. Other WireMock properties

Other than `wiremock.server.port`, `@AutoConfigureWireMock` populates the environment with some other properties too:

1. `wiremock.server.https-port`
2. `wiremock.server.stubs[]`
3. `wiremock.server.files[]`

#### 3. Gradle dependencies

To use Spring Cloud Contract WireMock in a Gradle based project, add the following dependency to your project:

```
testImplementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-contract-wiremock:${version}'
```

#### 4. Using in `application.yaml` files

If you configure your test `application.yaml` file like this:

```
sample:
  port: ${wiremock.server.port}
```

And define the following beans:

```java
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "sample")
@Data
public class PortProperties {
    private Integer port;
}

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
public class PortService {
    private final PortProperties config;

    public Integer getPort() {
        return config.getPort();
    }
}
```

You can verify that `sample.port` is set to the randomly chosen wiremock port:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureWireMock(port = 0)
public class PortServiceTest {
    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Autowired
    private PortService portService;

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnWireMockPort() {
        assertThat(portService.getPort())
                .isNotNull()
                .isEqualTo(Integer.parseInt(environment.getProperty("wiremock.server.port")));
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to create multiple wiremock instances when we are using @AutoConfigureWiremock annotation? I could not be successfully run tests in parallel with AutoConfigureWiremock annotation in JUnit 5 Spring-boot tests.

Comment: Is it possible to do this without `@SpringBootTest`? I'm trying to write a unit test with just `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)`

Answer (score 10):

Use property substitution in your application.properties:

`external.baseUrl=http://exampleUrl:${wiremock.server.port}`

This requires the `wiremock.server.port` property to be set before the SpringBootTest is initialised, which can be achieved by adding the `@AutoConfigureWireMock` annotation to your test class.

Comment: This won't work if the `wiremock.server.port` is only defined at runtime.

Comment: Will alter my answer to include a prerequisite

Answer (score 4):

I could not find a way to override properties in a Spring Boot integration test, since the test is run only after the application is created and all the beans already configured.

As a work around I added a `@TestConfiguration` to the test to replace the beans in the application:

```
private static WireMockServer wireMockServer1 = getWireMockServer();
private static WireMockServer wireMockServer2 = getWireMockServer();
private static WireMockServer wireMockServer3 = getWireMockServer();

private static WireMockServer getWireMockServer() {
    final WireMockServer wireMockServer = new WireMockServer(options().dynamicPort());
    wireMockServer.start();
    return wireMockServer;
}

@TestConfiguration
static class TestConfig {
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public BeanUsingAProperty1 getBean1() {
        BeanUsingAProperty myBean = new BeanUsingAProperty();
        myBean.setPort(wireMockServer.port());
        return myBean;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public BeanUsingAProperty2 getBean2() {
        String baseUrl = "http://localhost:" + wireMockServer2.port();
        return new BeanUsingAProperty2(baseUrl);
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public BeanUsingAProperty3 getBean3() {
        String baseUrl = "http://localhost:" + wireMockServer3.port() + "/request";
        return new BeanUsingAProperty3(new RestTemplate(), baseUrl, "someOtherParameter");
    }
}
```

This effectively replaced the `BeanUsingAProperty` with the one defined in the test so that it has the correct port number for Wiremock.

For this configuration to be picked up I had to add this class in the test annotation

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, classes = {
    MySpringBootApplication.class, MyIntegrationTest.TestConfig.class })
```

Note that I use the non-static Wiremock API, since I have several such external services that each need to be mocked. Note that how the different beans are built is different depending on how each was designed.

Answer (score 2):

When you use org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-contract-wiremock dependency, if you are a fan of annotation, you can just add `@AutoConfigureWireMock(port = Options.DYNAMIC_PORT)`

Answer (score 2):

In my use case (not using `SpringBootTest` annotation but `SpringJUnitConfig`) the property `wiremock.server.port` is valued to `0`.

Instead, using the SpEL `#{wireMockServer.port}` worked correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The approach I use to programmatically change a property when starting a Spring Boot app, is to pass the custom value into the application main entry-point `String[]` args. This will have the effect of over-riding all other means such as System properties, YML or other config files.

Here is an [example](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/mock/contract/PaymentService.java#L81):

```
String[] args = new String[]{"--my.prop=foo"};
SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
```

It will be easy for you to expose a static method or custom API which starts the Spring Boot app (for testing) and with the value you want.

And then, once you have the value of the wiremock port - things are easy.  Here is an example: [PaymentServiceContractTest.java](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/mock/contract/PaymentServiceContractTest.java#L24)

P.S. Karate (the open-source test examples I am using above) is a [new alternative to WireMock](https://hackernoon.com/api-consumer-contract-tests-and-test-doubles-with-karate-72c30ea25c18), do check it out ;)

Answer (score 0):

How are you reading `external.baseUrl`?
If you are using a `@Value` annotated property, you can use `ReflectionTestUtils` to set the port after you have setup the mock server.

```
ReflectionTestUtils.setField(yourTestClass, "youPort",  wireMockServer.port());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Thanks to brauls, refereeing to his repo, how feign client to make a request using wiremock, Junit 5 for testing with a random port

Git url --> https://github.com/brauls/spring-feign-wiremock-example

Add below entry in pom.xml

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-contract-wiremock</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-cloud-contract-wiremock.version}</version>
</dependency>

Add below entry in application-test.yaml

client:
  endpoint: http://localhost:${wiremock.server.port}/

Add below entry in all the junit classes

@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@AutoConfigureWireMock(port = 0)  


Add below method to mock the api respons in your junit classes where ever needed

@BeforeEach
void setUp() throws IOException {
     setupMockBooksResponse();
}

private  String setupMockBooksResponse() throws IOException {
    File mockResposeFile = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:" + "mocks/sample_stub.json");
    String content = "convert file content it into xml\json";
    ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
    String jsonInString = om.writeValueAsString("yourpojocloass");
    return stubFor(post("/api/v2/")
            .withHeader("Content-Type", equalTo("application/json"))
            .withHeader("Accept", equalTo("application/json"))
            .withRequestBody(WireMock.equalToJson(jsonInString))
            .willReturn(WireMock.aResponse()
                    .withStatus(HttpStatus.OK.value())
                    .withHeader("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                    .withBody(content))).toString();
}
```